# AppleScript weirdness

Tags: safari, applescript

I'm using this AppleScript to cycle through the tabs in Safari for a "dashboard" at work:

```
tell application "Safari"
repeat
    repeat with i from (count of tabs of window 1) to 1 by -1
        set thisTab to tab i of window 1
        set current tab of window 1 to thisTab
        delay 10
    end repeat
end repeat
end tell
```

The problem I am having is that when I put Safari into full screen, I get this error:

```
error "The variable thisTab is not defined." number -2753 from "thisTab"
```

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug.

Solution:

```
tell application "Safari"
    repeat
        repeat with i from (count of tabs of window 1) to 1 by -1
            tell window 1 to set current tab to tab i
            delay 10
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```